# Spring Boot 2.7.1 not working with Jetty 11

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, embedded-jetty

Jetty 9.x reported a vulnerability which is fixed in Jetty 11.x and in doing the upgrade it seems that Spring boot doesn't support it and throws

> java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext$Context does not implement the requested interface javax.servlet.ServletContext

Comment: Spring Boot supports JavaEE **not** JakartaEE. Jetty11 is a JakartaEE implementation and as such isn't supported by Spring Boot 2.7.x. Use Jetty10 which should be feature comparable with Jetty11 but is a JavaEE implementation.

Comment: Thanks Denium, I better switch to tomcat as Jetty 10 has the vulnerability and there is no specific reason for me to use jetty. Thanks again.

Comment: The latest releases of Jetty 10.x, Jetty 10.0.10 and 10.0.11, have no vulnerabilities.

Comment: Eclipse Jetty Dev here, the most recent release of [Jetty 9.4.48.v20220622, has no vulnerabilities too](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/8277).

Comment: @gauravbhatt13 the advisory now has a fixed version range - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-8mpp-f3f7-xc28

Answer (score 0):

See dependency compatibility tables by direct way (root pom.xml file) https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/